# Design Entities with union architecture concepts

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture, arangodb

according concepts of [Union Architecture](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/), my entities(POCO) exist in inner layer, and it didn't any dependency to another project or libraries.


 I'm using ArangoDB NoSql for my Data Access Layer, and I have to Use "ArangoDB Attribute" on my c# properties for mapping my properties to ArangoDD fields:

for example:

```
public class User
{
    [AliasField("_key")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

for this issue, I have to reference to Arango.Client Dll!:

[image]

Now, what I must be do for this problem? how can I remove my dependency?

any one can help me?

Answer (score 0):

It is the Onion architecture.

Indeed, your domain should not have any link to persistence.

As you can see in the diagram, persistence is part of the infrastructure layer.
You have to create a persistency layer that has a dependency to both your core model and ArangoDB.
There you could create entities annotated with the ArangoDB annotations and map them to your domain, or you could provide a mapping in another way so you don't need this translation between models.

Working with the onion architecture brings along more work, especially when setting up a new project, but it provides many benefits too.

Comment: thanks , I don't want to use your first solution(create a persistency layer that has a dependency to both your core model and ArangoDB).it's have very cost for me... second solution good seem! but how I do mapping? using with Auto Mapper?  I guess Auto Mapper don't solve my problem? is there any thing with name: **Proxy Attribute**?! I'm  little confused!

Answer (score 0):

If you use [ArangoDB.Client](http://arangoclient.net/) you can set mappings for naming conventions in addition to specify an attribute on class members

you can change how default identifiers naming convention are:

```
sharedSetting.Collection.ChangeIdentifierDefaultName(IdentifierType.Key, "Id");
```

or use the class name:

```
// this will resolve `UserId` => `_key`
sharedSetting.Collection.ChangeIdentifierDefaultName(IdentifierType.Key, (m) => $"{m.Name}Id");
```

or for other members:

```
sharedSetting.Collection.ChangeDocumentPropertyForType<User>(u => u.Id, p =>
{
    p.PropertyName = "_key";
});
```

you can read about how to use `SharedSetting` at http://arangoclient.net/Document/ArangoDatabase

note that `ArangoDB.Client` does not support ArangoDB 3.0 yet. the support will be added this month

Comment: thanks for answer, but I use [ArangoDB-NET](https://github.com/yojimbo87/ArangoDB-NET) driver